# Tesseract.Error in `shapeclustering': double free or corruption (out)

Tags: tesseract

What is the error may be? Tesseract 3.04.01

```
shapeclustering -F font_properties -U unicharset fontfile.box.tr
Reading fontfile.box.tr ...
*** Error in `shapeclustering': double free or corruption (out):      0x000000000251d1e0 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: can't this post could help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471909/training-tesseract-shapeclustering-issue

Comment: Read, core dumped It occurs after shapeclustering -F font_properties -U unicharset fontfile.box.tr . perhaps not so edited file .box?

Comment: I found a way out. [link](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/139)  script buildscript.sh  .And in what was a mistake, and I do not know, it's bad.